# questions about qdockwidget

Tags: qt, qdockwidget

I have a small program that displays two QDockWidgets aligned on the right hand side of the screen.

Initially the two dockwidgets remain nicely one beneath the other on the right side dock, but when I minimize and reshow the application the two dock widgets become spaced as if if they were trying to cover the vertical space uniformly. When I minimize again and reshow they are being displayed correctly as they were at the beginning. Can anyone explain what is happening? Can I control the layout of the docked widgets?

Another question is about what happens when I take the dock widgets out of the right side dock area. If I try to position one of the dock widgets on top of the already docked widget everything is fine, but when I try to position below Qt creates two tabs for each of the dock widgets. I do not want this behavior. I want the widgets one beneath the other at all times. Can this be done with Qt?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. In the main window do:

setDockOptions(!QMainWindow::AllowTabbedDocks);